# UIViewController with fixed header or footer like UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, header, uitableview, footer

in uitableviewcontroller, you have this header and footer that is pinned to the top and bottom respectively when scrolling.
i want to know if there is such thing in any apple made library class that has fixed footer and header that is not uitableviewcontroller because i don't want scrolling

```
UITableViewController
```

vs

```
UIViewController
```

i am thinking to customly add view to regular uiviewcontroller
but i just want to make sure i am not re-inventing the wheel

thanks

Comment: there are few post on SO to get fixed header to UITableView, have a look at them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewController does not have a header or footer. If you'd like to have either you would need to add a view as a subview to the controller just like you mentioned doing.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewControllers can have header and footer views, these aren't the same as UITableView header/footer views, since the UITableView header/footer views are contained within a UIScrollView.

An example of a header view, would be a UINavigationBar which is included in UINavigationController.  A footer view example would be the UITabBar of UITabBarController.

If you wish you implement custom header / footer views implement them manually by added them to the UIViewController view hierarchie then override these methods.

```
-(UIView*)rotatingFooterView{
  return _customFooterView;
}

-(UIView*)rotatingHeaderView{
  return _customHeaderView;
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/rotatingHeaderView